# URL hacking in symfony admin generator

Tags: php, security, symfony1

In symfony's admin generator, I can choose, for instance, to disable the delete and edit actions in generator.yml

Could a user change the URL and still access those functions, or should I also disable them in security.yml ?

Comment: Do they still work after you disable them (and clear the caches etc.)? It shouldn't be possible to run them (as their methods should be gone from the actions).

Comment: Oh, ok. That's what I wasn't sure of : do they still exist in the parent class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviosly, if you disable them in config, they will not work in any way unless you enable them again. Fabien is not stupid ;)

Comment: Nice, now all I need is to verify that the user has the rights to edit/delete that ID